# Reference to Javascript Library in Typescript project

Tags: typescript

My Project is in Typescript. In this project I want to refer or import another Javascript UI Library. Is there a Way of just importing them and **NOT** checking the Namespaces for those libraries while doing the "tsc".

For example, suppose the JS UI library has some classes called jsMyLibrary.ui.Button. My requirement is that while my tsc is running, it should not check for any string starting with jsMyLibrary*

Answer (score 0):

The default behaviour of **tsc** is to compile all .ts, .d.ts and .tsx files in your project. Javascript files will not be compiled unless this is specified in tsconfig.json. If 'jsMyLibrary' does contain some .ts or .d.ts files in the library and you don't want to compile these, it is possible to exclude certain files/file patterns in tsconfig.json:

```
"exclude": ["jsMyLibrary/**/*.ts"]
```

"exclude" defaults to some folders such as node_modules if it is not specified, read more about it [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#details)